# Classic ASP, file upload with HTTP POST request

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, http-post

I am trying to make HTTP POST request with file in classic ASP. The goal is to achieve same as common HTML form like bellow:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> <form method="POST" action="/upload_page.asp?category=5&subcategory=10" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works correctly. If I make POST request through a web form in browser, everything is fine.

Also, this could be done with cURL like this:

```
curl --form file=@./test.mp4
    "/upload_page.asp?category=5&subcategory=10"
```

The problem is, I am doing something wrong when try it in classic ASP. Here is the ASP code:

```
Dim adTypeBinary, adTypeText, adModeReadWrite
adTypeBinary  = 1
adTypeText = 2
adModeReadWrite = 3

Function StringToBinary(input)
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Charset = "UTF-8"
        stream.Type = adTypeText 
        stream.Mode = adModeReadWrite 
        stream.Open
        stream.WriteText input
        stream.Position = 0
        stream.Type = adTypeBinary 
        StringToBinary = stream.Read
        stream.Close
    set stream = Nothing
End Function

Function ReadBinaryFile(fullFilePath) 
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = 1
        stream.Open()
        stream.LoadFromFile(fullFilePath)
        ReadBinaryFile = stream.Read()
        stream.Close
    set stream = nothing
end function 

Dim boundary
boundary = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272"

' Generate data to be sent with HTTP POST
Dim BINARYPOST
Set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Type = adTypeBinary 
stream.Mode = adModeReadWrite     
stream.Open
stream.Write StringToBinary("" & boundary & vbCrLf & _ 
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; file=""" & Server.MapPath("test.mp4") & """" & _
"Content-Type: video/mp4" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
stream.Write ReadBinaryFile(Server.MapPath("test.mp4"))
stream.Write StringToBinary(vbCrLf & boundary & "--")
stream.Position = 0
BINARYPOST= stream.read
stream.Close

' Send HTTP POST
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
xmlhttp.open "POST", upload_url, false 
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
xmlhttp.send BINARYPOST
```

The problem with classic ASP approach is that I can't read the file data on second page.
I suspect maybe that server side page can't find the name of the file field (the variable name of field for upload is "file", like in working HTML example  ), but not sure about it.

Any idea what could be wrong with classic ASP request, so it doesn't send POST request on same way like HTML and PHP versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that there is a problem posting from ASP to a URL in the same virtual folder as the page doing the posting. Try posting to a handler on another server to verify whether or not this might be happening.

Comment: Thanks for trying Craig. It's highly appreciated. Unfortunately, I already tried to post on another server and get same problem. The best I can think of now is to go with custom component in .Net and call it from ASP page.